# how to use mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have transferred my website from old server to shared server.

All my code is in `"lfdata/main/com"` under `"public_html"` on the shared server.

The clean URL would look like follows:

```
http://ip-address/~name/how
```

and the rewritten URL should be:

```
http://ip-address/~name/lfdata/main/com/how.php
```

So can anyone suggest a rewrite rule for creating above URL?

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~[^/]+/lfdata/main/com/
RewriteRule ^(~[^/]+)/(.+) $1/lfdata/main/com/$2.php [L]
```

This will rewrite any request of `/~`*`name`*`/`*`foobar`* internally to `/~`*`name`*`/lfdata/main/com/`*`foobar`*`.php`.

Comment: QSA is not necessary if you don’t modify the query.

Comment: I have tried above but it not works?
Can I paste my .htaccess file here ?

Comment: <FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
</Files>
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
</IfModule>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~[^/]+/lf/main/com/
RewriteRule ^(~[^/]+)/(.+) $1/lf/main/com/$2.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: There is a `</IfModule>` missing. But why are you using those empty `<IfModule>` blocks anyway? And why do you have mod_rewrite dependent on mod_expires?

Comment: actually file is too big so i removed some content .There is any way to send this file to you?? so i will describe it my problem.
Can we solve it online ? If you do not mind.

Comment: Have you tried to put the mod_rewrite directives on top of the others?

Comment: yes I just tried but it shows "The page cannot be found" error

Comment: Try some debugging. Take a look into the server error log and at the logging feature of mod_rewrite (see RewriteLogLevel directive).

Comment: i tried RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-dRewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
# then add .html to get the actual filename
rewriterule (.*) lf/main/com/$1.php [L]

please go through this:http://74.220.215.241/~laborfa2/ 
this our url and click on "How it works" and see the url in browser .it looks like "http://74.220.215.241/~laborfa2/~laborfa2/how"
can you  please tell me what is going wrong??

Comment: You’re probably using relative URL paths rather than absolute ones.

Comment: Since I have not done this coding, I am really not able to find where the actual path is writeen.
in config it provides 
 "root"  => "/home/laborfa2/public_html/lf/main/",
"smarty"        => "/home/laborfa2/public_html/lf/var/smarty/",

Comment: Is that where we should provide? I think they are absolute now,,...any other place we need to make the change?

Answer (score 0):

this will do your rewrite including query string params

```
RewriteRule ^~name/how(.*)$ ~name/lfdata/main/com/how.php$1
```

Comment: The query cannot be matched with the RewriteRule directive. That’s only possible with the RewriteCond directive.